# In Slack API, is the ts field unique throughout the workspace or is it only unique to the channel?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a collection that stores slack messages from different channels. I want to identify a particular record with the ts. Is it possible that more than one message in any channel can have same ts value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp` for a message is unique for a channel, but not for a workspace. To uniquely identify a message in a workspace you need both `timestamp` and `channel`.

Example:

```
{
    "channel": "C024BE91L",
    "ts": "1401383885.000061"
}
```

This is why every API method that modifies a message requires both parameters. (e.g.[`chat.delete)`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete).